# Pass JSX component as child but specifying its params 'later'

Tags: reactjs

I have a React.js list component that I want to use as a generic list component.
Please see the current list component below:

```
const RepositoryList = () => {
    ...

    return (
        <div className='admin-container'>
            <div className='adminTitle text-center mb-5 fs-3'></div>
            <main>
                { !isLoading && !fetchError && 
                    <div className='col-6 mx-auto'>
                        <Table striped bordered hover>
                            <RepositoryListHeader />
                            <tbody>
                                {showedRepositories.map((repository) => (
                                    <RepositoryRow 
                                        key={repository.id} 
                                        record={repository} 
                                        formId={newRepositoryFormId}
                                        handleSave={handleSave}
                                        handleDelete={handleDelete} />
                                ))}
                                ...
    )
}

export default RepositoryList;
```

So I want the `RepositoryListHeader` and `RepositoryRow` to pass to my `AdminList` component which would look like

```
const AdminList = ( {headerEl, rowEl, ...} ) => {
    ...

    return (
        <div className='admin-container'>
            <div className='adminTitle text-center mb-5 fs-3'></div>
            <main>
                { !isLoading && !fetchError && 
                    <div className='col-6 mx-auto'>
                        <Table striped bordered hover>
                            {headerEl}
                            <tbody>
                                {showedRepositories.map((repository) => (
                                    {rowEl}
                                ))}
                                ...
    )
}

export default AdminList;
```

However I can pass the `repository.id`, ... values (which comes from **forEach** of `showedRepositories`) only in `AdminList` component and not in the parent of `AdminList` where all the parameter should defined.
For example:

```
    <AdminList 
         ...
         rowEl={ <RepositoryRow ??? />} />
```

Is there any way to resolve this?
I'd appreciate any help please.

Comment: I don't think I understand your question correctly. However, I think you can pass the element constructor in the props for `AdminList` instead of the element instance, that way you can pass the props you need from within the component that has access to them. As such: `<AdminList rowEl={RepositoryRow} />` and use it inside `AdminList` as `<rowEl />` (you may need to set the name to start with upper case letter since that's a requirement for React components' names.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use one of this ways:

**1)Passing data with a render prop :**

```html
const AdminList = ( {headerEl, renderRowEl} ) => {
  
  return (
      <div className='admin-container'>
          <div className='adminTitle text-center mb-5 fs-3'></div>
          <main>
              { !isLoading && !fetchError && 
                  <div className='col-6 mx-auto'>
                      <Table striped bordered hover>
                          {headerEl}
                          <tbody>
                              {showedRepositories.map((repository) => (
                                  {renderRowEl(repository)}
                              ))}
                              ...
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <AdminList
      headerEl={<RepositoryListHeader />}
      renderRowEl={(repository) => (
        <RepositoryRow
          key={repository.id}
          record={repository}
          formId={newRepositoryFormId}
          handleSave={handleSave}
          handleDelete={handleDelete}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

**2)render props as ReactComponent:**

```html
  const AdminList = ( {headerEl, rowEl} ) => {
      const HeaderEl = headerEl
      const RowEl = rowEl
      return (
          <div className='admin-container'>
              <div className='adminTitle text-center mb-5 fs-3'></div>
              <main>
                  { !isLoading && !fetchError && 
                      <div className='col-6 mx-auto'>
                          <Table striped bordered hover>
                              <HeaderEl />
                              <tbody>
                                  {showedRepositories.map((repository) => (
                                      <RowEl
                                        key={ repository.id }
                                        record={repository}
                                        formId={newRepositoryFormId}
                                        handleSave={handleSave}
                                        handleDelete={handleDelete}
                                      />
                                  ))}
                                  ...
      )
    }

    const App = () => {
      return (
        <AdminList
          headerEl= { RepositoryListHeader }
          renderRowEl= { RepositoryRow }
        />
      );
    };
```

Comment: Oh, absolutely brilliant! I went with the 1st option, thank you very much!